# ROC curve error

Tags: r, naivebayes, roc

I have dataset like this

```
train <- sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df)*0.80)
train <- df[train, ]
test <- df[-train, ]


NaiveBayes1 <-naiveBayes(purchased ~ .,data=train)
pre1 <- predict(NaiveBayes1,test,probability = TRUE)

library(pROC)
roc1 <- roc(test$purchased, pre1$posterior[,1])
```

And I get this error:

Error in pre1$posterior : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I have done in the class using LDA and it worked but for naivebays, it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last two lines from:

```
pre1 <- predict(NaiveBayes1, test, probability = TRUE)
roc1 <- roc(test$purchased, pre1$posterior[,1])
```

To:

```
pre1 <- predict(NaiveBayes1, test, type = "raw")
roc1 <- roc(test$purchased, pre1[,1])
```

Comment: pre1 <- predict(NaiveBayes1,test,type = raw)
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
.....this gave me new error...

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `type = "raw"` not `type = raw`. I've updated my answer and hopefully this should fix your problem